# Python for loops with an array

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I would like to create this for loop, but the text in the loop is quoted.
How can this be done please?
Thank you!
https://prnt.sc/tvutcl

Comment: Can you *share* the code on this platform, instead of a link.

Comment: also, try not to add the code in images

Comment: When you post the code directly into this question, include information on what the `data` object is. A pandas dataframe? If its pandas, basic location indexing is coverted in the docs [pandas.Dataframe.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: your question is not clear. what you want to achieve. please elaborate the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your image is in quotes, is an f-string, but they forgot to add the f

```
year = [2016,2017,2018,2019,2020]

for i in year:
   rtx_price = (data.loc[f'{year}-07-31', 'RTX'])
```

Comment: Hi. I still need to select the different dates each time, for example 2016 then 2017, then 2018 and so on.

Comment: well in this case, in the f string dont use year, use i

Comment: hi. i have another problem similar to this one.

Comment: current_ratio=[]
for i in range(len(year)):
    current_ratio.append(get_value(f'current_assets_{year[i]-1}'))
print(current_ratio)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tvyio9
when i print the array, the strings with current_assets_2016 and so on appear, while I want the numerical values attached to these strings as shown in the second ss
https://prnt.sc/tvyj8z

Comment: can you make a question of that problem?